# Calculation on a given set

Tags: notation

My question here is about a calculation on a given set A,
which has the following elements (1,2,...,k).

Which of the above elements has the set A-1 ?

I have already searched in the bibliography of set theory but unfortunately I didn't find something relative about it.

Best regards,
Theo

Comment: I literally don't understand the question. You defined $A=\{1,...,k\}$, then you want $A-1$? What does subtracting an integer from a set mean?

Comment: That's exactly my question. In a scientific paper I found that subtraction.

Comment: But, ... how are we supposed to know what you mean when you yourself don't know what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A=\{1,2,\dots,k\}$, then $A-1$ sometimes means $\{a-1: a \in A\}=\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$. 
 But some authors use $A-1$ to mean $A \setminus \{1\} = \{2,3,\dots,k\}$.  Does one of these interpretations make more sense in the context of the paper?

Comment: Thank you Rob! The second interpretation makes more sense in the context of the paper.